# Swiftmailer works but page is not shown

Tags: php, echo, swiftmailer

I have PHP send me an e-mail with swiftmailer when somebody fills in a form.

When I exclude the code of swiftmailer, and execute the form, I get my confirmationpage.

When I include the code of swiftmailer, the mail gets sent, but I don't get my confirmationpage. It just stays on the page of the form after a flicker.

The code to display the confirmation and the code to send the e-mail is all in the same file => registration.php.

Any help appreciated, kind regards.

The formprocessing code in PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registratie voltooid</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/global.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Resultaat   registratie</h1>
        <h2>Persoonlijke info</h2>
        <p><span class='green'>Succesvol</span> geüpload.</p><h2>Afbeeldingen</h2>
        <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_PSD, IMAGETYPE_BMP, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM);
        $input_file_name = "upload";
        $uploads_dir = "../uploads";
        $failed_uploads = [];
        $succeeded_uploads = [];
        foreach ($_FILES[$input_file_name]["error"] as $key => $error) {
            $name = $_FILES[$input_file_name]["name"][$key];
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {                                  //UPLOAD_ERR_OK equals errorcode 0 which stands for "no error"
                $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES[$input_file_name]['tmp_name'][$key]);
                if (in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes)) {
                    $tmp_name = $_FILES[$input_file_name]["tmp_name"][$key];
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir . "/" . $name);
                    $succeeded_uploads = $name;
                } else {
                    $failed_uploads[] = $name;
                }
            } else {
                if ($name != "") {
                    $failed_uploads[] = $name;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($succeeded_uploads) && empty($failed_uploads)) {
            echo "Alle afbeeldingen zijn <span class='green'>succesvol</span> geüpload</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p><span class='green'>Succesvol</span> geüpload: <span class='green'>" . count($succeeded_uploads) . "</span>.<br /><span class='red'>Niet succesvol</span> geüpload: <span class='red'>" . count($failed_uploads) . "</span>.";
        }

        require_once '../lib_swiftmailer/swift_required.php';
        //// Create the message
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
                ->setFrom(array('johndoe#derp.com'))
                ->setTo(array('johndoe#derp.com'))
                ->setBody($body)
                ->addPart($body, 'text/html') //alternative body
        ;
// add uploaded files as attachments
        if (!empty($uploads_dir)) {
            $files = glob("$uploads_dir/*.{jpg,png,gif,tiff,psd,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE); // paths in []
            foreach ($files as $AttachmentRelativePath) {
                $attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($AttachmentRelativePath);
                $message->attach($attachment);
            }
        }

// Set up transport and send
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.derpland.com', 587, 'tls')
                ->setUsername('xxxxx')
                ->setPassword('xxxxx')
        ;
        $transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $mailer->send($message);

// Remove files from uploaddir
        $allUploadedFiles = glob($uploads_dir . "/*");
        foreach ($allUploadedFiles as $file) {
            unlink($file);
        }
        ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

#

The form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PXL models</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/registration.css">
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <form action="php/registration.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="First_nameLabel" class="label">Voornaam</label>
        <input type="text" name="First_name" class="inputBox"/><br />
        <label for="Last_nameLabel" class="label">Naam</label>
        <input type="text" name="Last_name" class="inputBox"/><br />
        <label for="E-mailLabel" class="label">E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="E-mail" class="inputBox"/><br />
        <label for="Telephone" class="label">Telefoon</label>
        <input type="number" name="Telephone" class="inputBox"/><br />
        <label for="Cellphone" class="label">Gsm</label>
        <input type="number" name="Cellphone" class="inputBox"/><br />
        <label for="gender" class="label">Geslacht</label>
        <div class="surroundingDiv inputBox">
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" checked="checked" value="Vrouw">Vrouw
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Man">Man
        </div><br />
        <div id="uploadLabel" class="label">Uploaden</div>
        <div class="surroundingDiv">
            <label id="uploadButton">
                Upload foto's
                <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload[]" accept="image/*" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Bevestigen"><br /><br />
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Nowhere in your registration.php do you actually redirect anywhere, so once the email handling bit is done, that's where you stay.

Comment: I expected that the <h1>,<h2> right after <body> would be displayed. The same for the if:
if (!empty($succeeded_uploads) && empty($failed_uploads)) {
            echo "Alle afbeeldingen zijn <span class='green'>succesvol</span> geüpload</p>";
        } else.<br />

I have no problem with a redirection but I'm using variables of this page.

Comment: Are you using ajax to submit the form? Because I don't see how you could stay on your form page otherwise.